# Why does killing this subprocess raise a ProcessLookupError?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.4, python-3.3, kill

I can't understand when I need to kill subprocess.

```
for package in server.packages:
    n = subprocess.Popen(['which', package], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    n.wait()
    if n.returncode != 0:
        n.kill()
        <some other code>
```

I'm getting error (using Python3):

```
ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

Can anybody explain me when subprocess kill himself and when I need to do it manually ?

Comment: Just a side-note: [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) will return where the location of an executable is, and `None` if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, `Popen.wait` is a blocking call that waits for the subprocess to terminate. So there is normally no need to kill the subprocess after the call to `wait` returns. See Python docs on [Popen.wait()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Now, if you understand how that works, you can see that your code fails because at some point `Popen.returncode` returns a non-zero value and you then try to kill a process that does not exist any more.

This is why a `ProcessLookupError` is raised.

Now, as pointed out by another answer here, it is possible the returned value will be `None`, which indicates a possible (perhaps OS-specific) problem with the subprocess and could be checked for. The Python docs [merely state](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) that `None` indicates the process is still running (a negative value is also possible; see the docs for details).

Apart from that, if you need to kill a still-running subprocess for some reason, you either have to set and catch a timeout using:

```
   try:
      # time out in five seconds
      n.wait(timeout=5)
   except TimeOutExpired:
      # you can use kill, terminate or send_signal method; see the docs
      n.kill()
```

... or, alternatively, not use `wait` at all: Instead, let the subprocesses run while you do something else in your code, and then kill them later:

```
   import os

   processes = []
   for package in server.packages:
      n = subprocess.Popen(['which', package], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
      processes.append(n)

   <some other code while the subprocesses run (and possibly terminate)>

   for p in processes:
      try:
          p.kill()
      except OSError:
          # silently fail if the subprocess has exited already
          pass
```

What if you want to just check if the process is alive? Unfortunately, Python stdlib does not have a good, convenient way to check if a process is running. But, it can be conveniently done using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil), a third-party library. With it, checking if a process exists is as easy as:

```
   pid = n.pid # where n is a subprocess.Popen object from above examples
   import psutil
   psutil.pid_exists(pid) # returns True or False
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set a timeout of the process, once the timeout is attained then you can terminate the process by using:

```
n.terminate()
```

you can also use

```
.is_alive()
```

to check if the process or thread is alive or not and then terminate it if it has already attained the timeout.

Comment: This is partially wrong: ```.is_alive()``` is not a method that's available on ```subprocess.Popen``` objects.

Comment: Note that `n.terminate()` is not guaranteed to actually terminate the process. Under POSIX it sends the `SIGTERM` to the process, which may be caught and discarded or result in delayed termination. You'd then have to wait for the process to actually terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to examine the result from wait to determine why it returned. If it returns `None` the wait returned for other reasons than that the subprocess has terminated. If it returns other than `None` it would not be appropriate to `kill` the process, but that doesn't mean that it automatically is appropriate to `kill` it if it returned `None`.

For example, depending on OS the returning of `None` may indicate a state change for the process for which you wouldn't want to kill it. But also there may be scenarios where it returns `None`, but is still running an may terminate before you reach the `kill`.

So if you choose to `kill` the process you should probably enclose it in a `try`-`catch`-statement in order to handle the scenario where the subprocess has terminated.

Also from python3.3 you could add `timeout` (eg `n.wait(timeout=seconds_to_wait)` argument to wait in order to not wait indefinitely.

Your code might then look something like:

```
for package in server.packages:
    n = subprocess.Popen(['which', package], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    rc = n.wait() # in python3 you could supply timeout argument
    if rc != None:
        try:
            n.kill()
        except ProcessLookupError:
            pass
        code_to_run_when_killed()
    elif rc != 0:
        code_to_run_when_failed() # or perhaps you should raise exception
    else:
        code_to_run_when_exited_successfully()
```